# Mailx - Daily email of log file to list of recipients

Tags: solaris, mailx

I was given a few example usages of mailx and asked to come up with another by my manager.

I have a program that will be left running. Once a day, we want to send the log file it generates to a list of recipients.

This was the closest example I received

```
00 11 * * * unset noclobber;cat /home/emailList.txt /tools/temp/summary.csv | mailx  -t -s "Report `/bin/date`" -r person@company.com > /home/file.log
```

Seems like I want something like:

```
MyProgram | mailx -t -s "Report `/bin/date`" /home/emailList.txt -r person@company.com
```

But here, I'm not sending it once a day. This sends at MyProgram closing, right? I'm also sending MyProgram's output, not it's log file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `MyProgram; cat /home/emaillist.txt /path/to/MyProgam/log | mailx -t -s "Report \`/bin/date\`" -r person@company.com`.

Comment: Does this send the log file once a day?

Comment: You need to tell cron how frequent you want to run it. If you want once a day, let's say midnight, then you can specify `0 0 * * *` for the specification in your cron.